# Cannot Passing Data Between Pages with range selection

Tags: angularjs, local-storage, ionic-framework

I have a problem when making a mobile app with angular JS when passing data for next page with select option on first page. For next page cannot show anything just blank screen. For more detail, please check [my plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/OyRyApXrFUcnjgvfQ4GG?p=preview) to find what's wrong from my script. 
Its my "script.js" from my plunker:

```
angular.module('ex', [
  'ngRoute',
  'ngStorage',
])

.config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/view1', {
        templateUrl: 'view1.html',
        controller: 'View1Ctrl',
      })
      .when('/view2', {
        templateUrl: 'view2.html',
        controller: 'View2Ctrl',
      })
      .otherwise('/view1');
  }
])

.controller('View1Ctrl', ['$scope', '$location', '$localStorage',
  function($scope, $location, $localStorage) {
    $scope.view1 = $localStorage.view1 = {
      text: '',
      number: 0,
      type: '',
      discount: '',
    };

    $scope.producttype = [{
      product: "A",
      value: 7900000,
      discount1: 5612,
      discount2: 79000
    }, {
      product: "B",
      value: 10200000,
      discount1: 5612,
      discount2: 79000
    }, {
      product: "C",
      value: 11000000,
      discount1: 5612,
      discount2: 79000
    }, {
      product: "D",
      value: 7300000,
      discount1: 5612,
      discount2: 79000
    }, {
      product: "E",
      value: 10000000,
      discount1: 5612,
      potongan2: 79000
    }, {
      product: "F",
      value: 11200000,
      discount1: 5612,
      discount2: 79000
    }, ];

    $scope.submit = function() {
      $location.path('/view2');
    };
  }
])

.controller('View2Ctrl', ['$scope', '$localStorage',
  function($scope, $localStorage) {
    // I want show discount list based on "Discount Type" like "discount1" for "good" and "discount2" for "decent"
    if (view1.type == "Good") {
      view1.selection = view1.type.discount1;
      console.log(view1.discount);
    } else {
      view1.selection = view1.type.discount2;
      console.log(view1.discount);
    }

    $scope.view1 = $localStorage.view1;
  }
])
```

Beside that, How I can figure to show discount list based on "Discount Type" like "discount1" for "good" and "discount2" for "decent" in next page (view2.html)?

Thank you a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See updated [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/MEGSpQwZ62QE6ruteHh6?p=preview) here

Mailny, I hadded to the event that submit the save into localstorage,

```
$scope.submit = function() {
  $localStorage.view1 = $scope.view1;
  $location.path('/view2');
};
```

and changed several stuff in view2 to point to $scope.view1

```
 if ($scope.view1.type == "Good") {
  $scope.view1.selection = $scope.view1.type.discount1;
  console.log($scope.view1.discount);
} else {
  $scope.view1.selection = $scope.view1.type.discount2;
  console.log($scope.view1.discount);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but {{ view1.selection }} just show blank screen on view2.html, Could you check again?

Comment: Already checked you forget add 'view1' to '<form name="viewForm" ng-submit="submit()">' become '<form name="viewForm" ng-submit="submit(view1)">' and I already tested with my another script and worked. Because my another script forget add "$localstorage" feature. Thanks very much